# Get namespaces of a node with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to extract namespaces of a selected node with xslt

Suposse I have

```
<root xmlns:x1="url1" xmlns:x2="url2" ... xmlns:xN="urlN">
    <childNode1/>
    ...
    <childNodeN/>
</root>
```

How I could get

```
<namespace node="root">
    <x1>url1</x1>
    <x2>url2</x2>
    ...
    <xN>urlN</xN>
</namespace>
```

I have tried

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <namespace>
        <xsl:attribute name="node">
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*[contains(name(),'xmlns')]">
            <xsl:element name="{substring-after(name(),':')}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </namespace>
</xsl:template>
```

But  `@*[contains(name(),'xmlns')]` doesn't match anything.

Any help?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use the namespace axis if supported or in XSLT 2.0 and later the functions like `in-scope-prefixes()` that are meant to replace the namespace axis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you need to obtain the namespaces for the current node you should traverse the namespace axis.

So, for your example use this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="namespace::*">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
```

---  edit

The value of name() will be an empty string for the default namespace, so you can use a xsl:if or xsl:when to test for it.

```
<xsl:for-each select="namespace::*">
  <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="name()">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
        <!-- handle default namespace here -->

     </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>    
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: I would add a warning that the `<xsl:element name="{name()}">` way to output a namespace does not work with a default namespace declaration `<foo xmlns="http://example.com">...</foo>`. Of course the namespace axis can be used but a different output format is needed.

Comment: @MartinHonnen - your absolutely right of course - a test will be required for the default namespace but hey! its a quick answer that fits the question and lets be honest, the OP could have easily discovered the answer with just a litle of research ;-)

Comment: so, how to match the default namespace declaration?

Comment: I've updated the answer to cover the default namespace